# Websphere admin console restart

Tags: websphere

Recently I ecountered situation where my WebSphere's admin console stop responding (tired to open it and got timeout). It happened after I've made some changes and saved them. 
All the WebSphere application server and nodeAgent was working (checked in serverStatus.sh -all). I could still access my Web Application.
**Is there a way to restart just admin console with a script or do I have to restart everything?**

In my case the WebSphere works on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if someone will be interested. My dmgr process couldn't stop so I have to kill it manualy. Then I had to run startManager.sh script in IBM websphere dmgr location. It's done without restart the whole server.